# Linq is not giving data in proper order

Tags: linq

I am facing an issue while using linq query. I am getting around 600000 records from database using a proc. And for every input, I'm filtering it with LINQ. Order of the data rows does not remain same after filtering it with LINQ query. Has anybody faced this issue before?

Thanks,

Comment: It's impossible to tell what's going on without seeing any of your query code. What order are you assuming in the first place? Are you enforcing that at all?

Comment: @Jon Skeet, I'm guessing not, but as you state, its impossible to tell from the question.

Answer (score 2):

> Order of the data rows does not remain same after filtering it with LINQ query.

Most LINQ operators don't guarantee ordering.  If you want guaranteed ordering, you should use `OrderBy` to specifically order your query results by the appropriate column(s).

Answer (score 0):

If you don't specifiy an order and your database has mutiple processors then there is no garauntee that the order will remain consistent between calls.

If you don't order your data the database engine can send the request to several threads and just aggregate the results as they are processed by each thread. If the server can process the threads concurrently then that order will be indeterminate.

On the up side, you know you are getting data as quickly as possible.

**EDIT**

The same is true for the implementation of Linq. If no order is specified then the framework is free to perform the statement in any way the enumerates the correct result.

Comment: I have written this query for filtering using LINQ                 var data=from rows in tableData where rows["CompanyId"].ToString() == compID orderby rows["number"] select rows;   But still its not in correct order in "data" variable

Comment: @rohit I would ask the question again including that info